# Table to XML using TSQL with facet grouping and counts

Tags: sql-server, xml, common-table-expression

I have a requirement to turn a table into XML with counts for values.

e.g.

```
Table
Id , Type, AnotherType
1, This, Widget
2, This, Fimble
3, That, Widget
```

I want the output something like this. This needs to be dynamic so new columns or facets added would generate the this type of output.

```
<matrix name="Type">
 <facet name = "this" count=2>
   <id value = 1></id>
   <id value = 2></id>
 </facet>     
 <facet name = "that" count=1>
   <id value = 3></id>
 </facet>
</matrix>
<matrix name="AnotherType">
 <facet name = "Widget" count=2>
   <id value = 1></id>
   <id value = 3></id>
 </facet>
 <facet name = "Fimble" count=1>
   <id value = 2></id>
 </facet>
</matrix>
```

Is this possible?

If the columns/values change, I'd like a solution that handles that - e.g it will generate a new matrix and facts dependant on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but you need to apply `UNPIVOT` command and dynamic SQL. It is better when you divide this into steps:

**1)** Your table can have various columns. What you should to first is to get the list of columns. All the columns are listed in `sys.columns` table. The following piece of code will get the list of columns and save it as comma delimited list. However, first column is stored separatly (becuase of the further purpose).

```
DECLARE @firstColumn NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @columnList NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @firstColumn = name 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) 
        AND column_id = 1
SET @columnList = N''

SELECT @columnList = @columnList + name + N',' 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) 
        AND column_id > 1

SET @columnList = LEFT(@columnList,LEN(@columnList)-1)
```

**2)** You want to use `UNPIVOT` ([documentation here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)) command to make the structure more "programmer friendly". We need the list of columns to do that. It can be done using dynamic SQL ([example here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160)). The following command does the job:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cmd = N'INSERT INTO #unPivoted
    SELECT id, Matrixes, Facets 
    FROM 
        (SELECT ' + @firstColumn + N',' + @columnList + N' FROM ' + @tableName + N') p
    UNPIVOT
        (Facets FOR Matrixes IN(' + @columnList + N')) AS unpvt
    ORDER BY Matrixes,Facets,id'

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
```

In your example it will generate result like this:

```
id | Matrixes    | Facets
-------------------------
2  | AnotherType | Fimble
1  | AnotherType | Widget
3  | AnotherType | Widget
3  | Type        | That
1  | Type        | This
2  | Type        | This
```

**3)** The last thing is the actual query. It is enough to use `FOR XML AUTO` command. You should however make some nested queries to make the structure look like you want:

```
SELECT matrix.name, facet.name, facet.id_count AS count, id.id AS value 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Matrixes AS name FROM #unPivoted) matrix
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Matrixes AS matrix_name, Facets AS name, COUNT(id) AS id_count FROM #unPivoted GROUP BY Matrixes, Facets) facet 
    ON matrix.name = facet.matrix_name 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Facets AS facet_name, id FROM #unPivoted) id 
    ON facet.name = id.facet_name
ORDER BY matrix.name, facet.name, id.id
FOR XML AUTO
```

And the stored procedure. I left all the PRINTs and SELECTs for you to see how does it work (if the description is not enought).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_tableToXML
    @tableName NVARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- 1. Get columns from the table
DECLARE @firstColumn NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @columnList NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @firstColumn = name 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) 
AND column_id = 1

SET @columnList = N''

SELECT @columnList = @columnList + name + N',' 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) 
AND column_id > 1

SET @columnList = LEFT(@columnList,LEN(@columnList)-1)

PRINT @firstColumn
PRINT @columnList

-- 2. Unpivot the table
CREATE TABLE #unPivoted
(
    id INT,
    Matrixes VARCHAR(30),
    Facets VARCHAR(30)
)

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cmd = N'INSERT INTO #unPivoted
SELECT id, Matrixes, Facets 
FROM 
    (SELECT ' + @firstColumn + N',' + @columnList + N' FROM ' + @tableName + N') p
UNPIVOT
    (Facets FOR Matrixes IN(' + @columnList + N')) AS unpvt
ORDER BY Matrixes,Facets,id'

PRINT @cmd

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd

SELECT * FROM #unPivoted

-- 3. The query
SELECT matrix.name, facet.name, facet.id_count AS count, id.id AS value 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Matrixes AS name FROM #unPivoted) matrix
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Matrixes AS matrix_name, Facets AS name, COUNT(id) AS id_count FROM #unPivoted GROUP BY Matrixes, Facets) facet 
    ON matrix.name = facet.matrix_name 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Facets AS facet_name, id FROM #unPivoted) id 
    ON facet.name = id.facet_name
ORDER BY matrix.name, facet.name, id.id
FOR XML AUTO

END
GO

EXEC usp_tableToXML 'Types'
```

Btw, I guess that you made a little mistake in your XML structure. Shouldn't it be like this (`facet` tag should be closed after ids?):

```
<matrix name="AnotherType">
  <facet name="Fimble" count="1">
    <id value="2" />
  </facet>
  <facet name="Widget" count="2">
    <id value="1" />
    <id value="3" />
  </facet>
</matrix>
<matrix name="Type">
  <facet name="That" count="1">
    <id value="3" />
  </facet>
  <facet name="This" count="2">
    <id value="1" />
    <id value="2" />
  </facet>
</matrix>
```

Comment: I have accepted this, however ideally this would need to work off a query not a table but excellent work. Really good stuff.

Comment: I adapted this so that the code is used within the proc; again, fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2005 or later you can do something like [this](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/data-as-xml-sql-server).

Comment: This is just a post on  how to output XML, I dont think this is a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here: [CTE and Hierarchical XML Result](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dmauri/articles/4123.aspx). You can ignore XSLT part and stick with XML alone.

**EDIT:** Seems it's a bit more trick. Please take a look here: [SQL XML output to populate a treeview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlxml/thread/c80a3283-f759-40bd-81bc-cd30a3d0dc6b) as it uses a pure TSQL CTE instruction to generate your hierarchical XML.

Comment: This doesnt look like an elegant solution or one that would work for my scenario. I'd also like a pure TSQL solution, I am sure it is possible using a CTE in combination with maybe some explicit XML.